# How to show a WPF modal window over a WPF popup?

Tags: wpf, popup, modal-dialog

I have a WPF app where I make my screen dark and show the user a popup for him to fill in some data.

One of the controls hosted in that popup might raise a modal window asking the user to confirm some validation results, when that modal is raised it doesn't show because the popup takes precedence in the UI.

Is there a way to force the modal be shown over the popup?

Comment: Well this time I fixed it by using the "TopMost" property of the modal window. Not that I like it since it moves the modal window on top of every window, even the windows of programs not related to my app. But it works.